# VEF/USD trading option

Tags: options, foreign-exchange, currency, derivatives

Does there exist a VEF/USD (Venezuelan bolivar) spot or derivative market on any public exchange?

Comment: Of possible interest: [Why are there two exchange rates for Venezuela's currency?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/61117/35567) and [Why do people buy US dollars on the black market?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/14764/35567).

Answer (score 3):

No, because the VEF is officially pegged to the USD at the rate of 6.35:1, so there is no official need for price discovery (which is the purpose of a market).

However, the official rate is not the [black market rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venezuelan_bol%C3%ADvar), and the reason there's a black market is precisely because there's no regular market.